# Freeze list header Row while Scrolling in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, css

How to freeze list header row while scrolling in SharePoint?

Comment: Have you tried http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75365/freeze-header-row?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used the sticky headers library to add fixed headers to out of the box SharePoint list views. Works in both standard and quick mode in SharePoint Online. I put a link to the script in a Script Editor web part on the view where i want this functionality. I believe you can also add to the master page for cross site implementation.

http://spoodoo.com/sticky-headers-in-sharepoint-2013/

This is from a previous post:

[SharePoint fixed table header](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/157621/sharepoint-fixed-table-header/164330#164330)